# Remove special NTFS permission from folder

Tags: powershell, acl

Below is the code I am currently using to remove the special NTFS permission from folder

```
$path = "F:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn"
$acl = get-acl $path
icacls $path /reset /t /c /l /q
 icacls $path /inheritance:d
Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $acl

# Check the existing rights
$acl.Access | where IdentityReference -Like 'BUILTIN\Users'

# Get a list of the rules to remove
$rules = $acl.access | Where-Object { 
    !$_.IsInherited -and 
    $_.IdentityReference -like 'BUILTIN\Users' -and
    $_.FileSystemRights -in 'CreateFiles, AppendData'
}

ForEach($rule in $rules) {
    $acl.RemoveAccessRule($rule)
}

$acl.Access
Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $acl
```

This code is working fine and removing the special permission from the folder. But the problem is the folder is also having 2 **SYSTEM** permission. 1 applies to this folder and another applies to folder and subfolder.
The script is removing the first **SYSTEM** permission as well which is for this folder.

[image]

Please let me know what is issue here.

**Addition:** I just identified that once **icacls $path /reset /t /c /l /q** command is executing, it is removing the **SYSTEM** permission.

Comment: I recommend you take a look at the [NTFSSecurity module](https://github.com/raandree/NTFSSecurity). It makes stuff like this a lot simpler. There is an [intro guide here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/fieldcoding/ntfssecurity-tutorial-1-getting-adding-and-removing-permissions) and [docs here](https://ntfssecurity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

You have included `!$_.IsInherited` and the first `System` permission is not inherited from F:\ like the others. So it's included in the result and you remove it.

Comment: ok. but I am specifically mentioning to go for 'BUILTIN\Users' only.

Comment: Add `$_.IdentityReference -notlike 'SYSTEM'` this will do the trick.

Comment: I added that extra check but still it is removing the SYSTEM permission.

Comment: `-and $_.IdentityReference -notlike '*SYSTEM'`. It's because SYSTEM is in reality `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`

Comment: Tried by giving full name itself. but same issue.  and problem is as i updated my question, while resetting the permissions, it is removing the SYSTEM permission.

Comment: yes this is how work icalcs /reset : replaces ACLs with default inherited ACLs for all matching files. So that all ACLs that are not inherited are removed, and so you remove System which is not inherited. But you can always add `SYSTEM Full Control Folder, subFolders and Files` on the F: drive so that the ACE will be restored

Comment: These are existing structure which is now in place. I can't do any modification to structure. using script only I have keep it.

Comment: updating a security descriptor is not modifying the hierarchy of files and folders. You can propagate an ACE from top to bottom (like from "F": to "F:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn") without changing anything on the structure.

Comment: I am sorry but I am not getting what you are trying to explain. Is it possible to show it through some example?