# Issue while executing icacls command

Tags: powershell

I have below folder permissions with me

```
[DBG]: PS C:\Windows\system32>> $acl.Access | ft

           FileSystemRights AccessControlType IdentityReference      IsInherited                InheritanceFlags PropagationFlags
           ---------------- ----------------- -----------------      -----------                ---------------- ----------------
                FullControl             Allow NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM          False                            None             None
                FullControl             Allow BUILTIN\Administrators        True ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit             None
                FullControl             Allow NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM           True ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit             None
                  268435456             Allow CREATOR OWNER                 True ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit      InheritOnly
ReadAndExecute, Synchronize             Allow BUILTIN\Users                 True ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit             None
                 AppendData             Allow BUILTIN\Users                 True                ContainerInherit             None
                CreateFiles             Allow BUILTIN\Users                 True                ContainerInherit             None



[DBG]: PS C:\Windows\system32>>
```

Once I am executing below command to remove the Inheritance, It is removing the first entry

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $acl.Access | ft

           FileSystemRights AccessControlType IdentityReference      IsInherited                InheritanceFlags PropagationFlags
           ---------------- ----------------- -----------------      -----------                ---------------- ----------------
                FullControl             Allow BUILTIN\Administrators        True ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit             None
                FullControl             Allow NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM           True ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit             None
                  268435456             Allow CREATOR OWNER                 True ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit      InheritOnly
ReadAndExecute, Synchronize             Allow BUILTIN\Users                 True ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit             None
                 AppendData             Allow BUILTIN\Users                 True                ContainerInherit             None
                CreateFiles             Allow BUILTIN\Users                 True                ContainerInherit             None



PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Command : `icacls $path /inheritance:d`

Please let me know what is solution so it should not delete any entry

My main goal is to remove **FileSystemRights with AppendData and CreateFiles**

Comment: You play with commands you don't highly understand. And between each answer you have modified permissions. This is the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69658614/remove-special-ntfs-permission-from-folder/69658726?noredirect=1#comment123133137_69658726) you posted 1h ago.
Here you modify the inheritance, while you want to update rights.

Comment: @Hazrelle: I am debugging the code and exploring my options on what might cause the issue. so going all together, I am trying to go piece by piece. Appreciate if yo can help.

Comment: There is no issue with icalcs. The command works fine for a decade now for thousand of people everyday. You don't debug anything for the moment you just invoke a command. [Security descriptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/7d4dac05-9cef-4563-a058-f108abecce1d) are complex objects. It does contains a DACL (discretionary access control list) which contains many [ACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/d06e5a81-176e-46c6-9cf7-9137aad4455e). Inheritance may propagate some ACE in a hierarchy, like files and folders.

Comment: The table itself represent the DACL.
The line you see in the table represent an ACE.
FileSystemRights is a property of an ACE. So for who do you want to remove the AppendData and CreateFiles rights ? 
Next refer to values regarding [masks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/file-and-directory-access-rights-constants) so that you can modify the value of FileSystemRights (yes Full Control is a numeric value) and then you may be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: Want to remove for BUILTIN\Users. but while doing that as the SYSTEM permission is not inherited, it is also getting removed along with that

Comment: No you didn't modified BUILTIN\Users with /inheritance:d. You have modified how ACE are propagated in the hierarchy. 
But the BUILTIN\Users ACE seems inherited from drive F:
So you have 2 choices:
- remove AppendData and CreateFiles for BUILTIN\Users on the whole drive F:
- break the inheritance on a specific folder by copying inherited ACE so that they become uninherited ACE, and then modify the rights for BUILTIN\Users on this folder.
Which choice ?

Comment: whole F: drive I can't do because there are only specific folder paths where this permission is there. so I think 2nd option is the way.

Comment: I'm not so sure. Because the ACE is granted on the drive, most of the time a new folder/file inherit ACE from the parent. Unless the inheritance is explicitly disabled. So I would say that by default the BUILTIN\Users ACE is everywhere on the drive.

Comment: even I am not sure. but even the first option what you are telling, if it will not remove any other permissions apart from builtin\users, then that also will work for me. now my biggest worry is that because there are other folders where apart from SYSTEM, some other users are also having Isinherited as none

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238408/discussion-between-hazrelle-and-empty-coder).

Answer (score 0):

To break inheritance on any specific folder by copying inherited ACE:
Doing so will keep the ACE that do exist now. But if someone grant a user or group on the drive in the future, this folder will never get the new ACE.
`icacls F:\Folder\Folder /inheritance:d`

To modify `BUILTIN\Users` by removing AppendData and CreateFiles (this can be done directly on F: drive, but be cautious):

- `icacls F:\Folder\Folder /grant:r BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)RX`

or

- `icacls F:\Folder\Folder /grant:r BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(GR,GE,S)`

`(GR GE S)` = `RX`
Test it carefully on a test folder.

This may not fully work as expected because of differences in object inheritance flags. In such case remove all ACEs for `BUILTIN\Users` and grant one of the two above.
`icacls F:\Folder\Folder /remove:g BUILTIN\Users`

And just for information, you can also modify the permissions with a graphical user interface (right-click on the folder, properties, and select the security tab. There is the advanced mode which is very powerful.

**EDIT REGARDING NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM**

`icalcs F:\Folder\Folder` output:

- `AUTHORITY NT\SYSTEM:(F)`
- `AUTHORITY NT\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)`

But the GUI display only:

- `SYSTEM   |   Full Control   |  This folder, subfolders and files`

The matching icacls / GUI translations are:

- `AUTHORITY NT\SYSTEM:(F)` => `SYSTEM   |   Full Control   |  This folder only`
- `AUTHORITY NT\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)` => `SYSTEM   |   Full Control   |  subfolders and files only`

So the GUI is smart enough to sum the inheritance flags and produce a `this folder, subfolders and files` equivalent to `(OI)(CI)`.

Icacls / GUI translation:

- no inheritance: "this folder only"
- (OI): "this folder and files"
- (CI): "this folder and subfolders"
- (CI)(IO): "subfolders only"
- (OI)(IO): "files only"
- (OI)(CI)(IO): "subfolders and files only"
- (OI)(CI): "this folder, subfolders and files"

The (NP) concern how the ACE is **NOT** propagated to children of the hierarchy. Let's say we have the following hierarchy:

- Folder

  - SubFolder

    - SubFolder1
    - File1
  - File

Here the different behaviors:

- (OI)(NP): "this folder and files" => ACE on Folder and File but **NOT** on File1.
- (CI)(NP): "this folder and subfolders" => ACE on Folder and SubFolder but **NOT** on SubFolder1.
- (CI)(IO)(NP): "subfolders only" => ACE on Folder and SubFolder but **NOT** on SubFolder1.
- (OI)(IO)(NP): "files only" => ACE on Folder and File but **NOT** on File1.
- (OI)(CI)(IO)(NP): "subfolders and files only" => ACE on Folder, SubFolder and File, but **NOT** on SubFolder1 and **NOT** on File1.
- (OI)(CI)(NP): "this folder, subfolders and files" => ACE on Folder, SubFolder and File, but **NOT** on SubFolder1 and **NOT** on File1.

Regarding the user granted with `icacls F:\Folder\ /grant BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(GR,GE,S)` this is translated by icacls into 2 ACES:

- BUILTIN\Users:(RX) => "this folder only"
- BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(IO) => "subfolders and files only"
  And so can be merged by the GUI with "this folder, subfolders and files"

This behavior only happens with **specific** rights of `icacls` and only when the sum of **specific** rights match a **simple** right (ie (S,GE,GR) = RX). This doesn't appear using **simple** rights.
`icacls F:\Folder\ /grant BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)RX` translate to 1 ACE only.

When adding the propagation (NP) with **specific** rights it becomes fancy:
(OI)(NP)(GR,GE,S)

- Folder: (RX) and (OI)(NP)(GR,GE,S)
- SubFolder: Nothing
- File: (I)(RX) => Inherited

Comment: I checked the code but it is adding a BUILTIN\Users permission, not deleting.
`ReadAndExecute, Synchronize             Allow BUILTIN\Users                False ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit             None`

Comment: Yes I've seen it's because of InheritanceFlags. I've updated to include a third command to remove all ACEs granted to BUILTIN\Users

Comment: yes it deleted the new created permissions but no effect on the AppendData and CreateFiles part